# Aligning memory when allocating on heap

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, alignment

I came across this example implementation of the `new()` operator in C++:

```
void *operator new(size_t size){
    if(void *mem = malloc(size)){
        cout << "allocated memory" << endl;
        return mem;
    }
    else{
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
}
```

How would one edit this function so that memory could be allocated on particular "byte boundaries" (I am referring to data *alignment* discussed in performance circles)?

(I am assuming this is not just done automatically by the compiler- or if it is, are there any advantages to implementing it manually?)

Comment: Use `posix_memalign` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [aligned malloc() in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc)

Comment: not a duplicate, but [this probably answers the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504776/aligned-malloc-in-c) (the linked question asks how a specific algorithm works, not a general how-to solution).

Comment: The result of `malloc` will be suitably aligned for any object type, so you only need to worry if you have special alignment needs, like aligning to a cache or page boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to find a way to retain the original pointer, otherwise your `free` will go horribly bad.

Aligning is a simple case of (assuming that `alignment` is a 2<sup>n</sup> value):

```
 void *aligned = reinterpret_cast<void *>(
        (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(mem) + alignment-1) & ~(alignment-1));
```

However, like I said, you will need to save the original pointer somewhere. This probably means allocating "a bit extrra" (e.g `sizeof(void *)`).

So we end up with something like this:

```
 assert(!(alignment & alignment-1)); // Don't like aligment not power of 2.

 size_t extra = sizeof(void *);
 void *mem = malloc(size + extra + alignment-1); 
 if (!mem) 
    throw bad_alloc();

 void *aligned = reinterpret_cast<void *>(
        (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(mem) + extra + alignment-1) & ~(alignment-1));
 void **ptr = reinterpret_cast<void **>(aligned); 
 ptr[-1] = mem;
 return aligned;
```

Then in the operator delete, you need to dig out your original pointer:

```
 operator delete(void *mem)
 {
    void **ptr = reinterpret_cast<void **>(mem); // This is the "aligned" pointer. 
    void *orig_mem = ptr[-1]; 
    free(orig_mem);
 }
```

Comment: You are missing a bitwise negation of `(alignment-1)` when applying the bitwise and operation on the memory address.

Comment: @Oxygene: Thanks, it's only been wrong for a little over a year... ;)

Comment: It's never too late ;)