# Implement aligned_malloc using malloc in C

Tags: c, memory, alignment, malloc

Question:
    why do we declare `p2` as `void **`? why not `p2*`?

we are returning p2, but our return function type is `void *`. This doesn't make any sense. Compiler will say unmatch return type.

```
void *aligned_malloc(size_t required_bytes, size_t alignment) {
    void *p1;
    void **p2;
    int offset=alignment-1+sizeof（void*);
    p1 = malloc(required_bytes + offset);               // the line you are missing
    p2=(void**)(((size_t)(p1)+offset)&~(alignment-1));  //line 5
    p2[-1]=p1; //line 6
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504776/aligned-malloc-in-c

Comment: I think Maria got the function from the above link. But she is asking a different question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void**` can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so there shouldn't be a type problem.

The reason it's declared `void**` is to make it convenient to store the allocated pointer just in front of it.

It works like this code, which uses another variable:

```
void *aligned_malloc(size_t required_bytes, size_t alignment) {
    void *p1;
    void *p2;
    void **p3;
    int offset=alignment-1+sizeof（void*);
    p1 = malloc(required_bytes + offset);
    p2= (void*)(((size_t)(p1)+offset)&~(alignment-1));
    p3 = (void**) p2; 
    p3[-1]=p1;
    return p2;
}
```

Comment: so basically, `void **` is to make it become array. And the reason to make it become array is because we need to store the allocated pointer?